# How to sanitize settings API value

Tags: settings-api, sanitization

I am working on a Plugin. I am using Settings API like below.

```
register_setting( 'sports_api_key', 'sports_api_key' );
```

How can I sanitize settings API Text value here ?

Comment: Did you look at the docs? You can pass a sanitization callback as part of the 3rd argument: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/

Answer (score 2):

Add a third parameter, which is an $args array, and add your sanitization callback in there:

```
register_setting( 
    'sports_api_key', 
    'sports_api_key', 
    array(
        'sanitization_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'
    )
);
```

This is enough for your use case, the `sanitize_text_field` function already exists, so you don't need to create it.

More information [here for how to add a sanitization callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) and [here to sanitize text fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/).